# How to select 7 consecutive days for each id?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data that contains everyday data for each id. I have unique 96 ids. So for each id there are 365 days recorded like

```
   date   ids   data
01.01.2022  1   0
02.01.2022  1   0
03.01.2022  1   0
04.01.2022  1   0
05.01.2022  1   0
06.01.2022  1   321
07.01.2022  1   0
08.01.2022  1   0
09.01.2022  1   0
10.01.2022  1   0
11.01.2022  1   0
12.01.2022  1   0
13.01.2022  1   0
14.01.2022  1   0
15.01.2022  1   0
16.01.2022  1   0
17.01.2022  1   0
18.01.2022  1   0
19.01.2022  1   0
20.01.2022  1   0
21.01.2022  1   0
01.01.2022  2   434
02.01.2022  2   0
03.01.2022  2   0
04.01.2022  2   0
05.01.2022  2   0
06.01.2022  2   0
07.01.2022  2   0
…       
01.05.2022  1   3213
02.05.2022  1   0
03.05.2022  1   0
04.05.2022  1   0
05.05.2022  1   0
06.05.2022  1   0
07.05.2022  1   0
08.05.2022  1   0
09.05.2022  1   0
```

So I need to select the first 7 days from the point where the `data` column is not 0 or null. From this example, we can see that I should get all rows between 06.01.2022 and 12.01.2022 for id - 1, and between 01.01.2022 and 07.01.2022 for id - 2, and so on. In addition, the id can be repeated again on other dates. For example, for id there is new data on 01.05.2022, so we take this data too with the next 7 consecutive days. How select query will look for this question in PostgreSQL? I hope I could deliver the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all non-zero and non-null rows in a [`with` CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) and [join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-join.html) that with your table, adding anything up to 6 days from that - assuming you're after first 7 days *including* the one with non-empty data.

```sql
with first_non_zeros as (
  select ids,date
  from test 
  where data<>0 --and data is not null --the "not null" isn't necessary
)
select t.* 
  from test t 
     inner join first_non_zeros f 
        on t.ids=f.ids and t.date-f.date between 0 and 6
order by ids,date;
```

```
   date    | ids | data
-----------+-----+------
2022-01-06 |   1 |  321
2022-01-07 |   1 |    0
2022-01-08 |   1 |    0
2022-01-09 |   1 |    0
2022-01-10 |   1 |    0
2022-01-11 |   1 |    0
2022-01-12 |   1 |    0
2022-05-01 |   1 | 3213
2022-05-02 |   1 |    0
2022-05-03 |   1 |    0
2022-05-04 |   1 |    0
2022-05-05 |   1 |    0
2022-05-06 |   1 |    0
2022-05-07 |   1 |    0
2022-01-01 |   2 |  434
2022-01-02 |   2 |    0
2022-01-03 |   2 |    0
2022-01-04 |   2 |    0
2022-01-05 |   2 |    0
2022-01-06 |   2 |    0
2022-01-07 |   2 |    0
```

[Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/iGuVRgl2)